# Printing wide HTML tables without cutting off the right side

Tags: html, css, printing

I know this question has been on here plenty of times, but I haven't found an answer that specifically addresses my question.  I have a table that I am trying to print that is 16 columns wide.  Of course, the right side just cuts off in every browser.  I am trying to figure out a way to prevent that from happening.  At the bottom is a sample table, try printing it and the right side cuts off.  Here are options that unfortunately I can't do:

- Force landscape mode
- Using `word-break:break-all`. It just isn't nice looking

Ideally I would just want the table to take up as much width as it needs, and if there is too much content then just wrap it normally so the letters in the words stay together.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<style>
body {
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-family: Garamond, Serif;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
td, th {
  padding: 2px 2px 2px 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
tr.tableTitle {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  background: #d0d0d0;
}

thead tr {
  font-weight: bold;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  text-align: center;
}
button.expander {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: black;
  font-family: Verdana, Serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 5px 10px 0px;
  background: #ffffff;
} 
@media print {
  button.expander{
    display: none;
    margin: 0px;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="section">
<button class="expander">-</button>
<table>
<thead>
<tr class="tableTitle"><th colspan="16">Table Header</th></tr>
<tr>
<th>Column A</th>
<th>Column B Column B Column B</th>
<th>Column C</th>
<th>Column D</th>
<th>Column E</th>
<th>Column F</th>
<th>Column G Column G</th>
<th>Column H</th>
<th>Column I</th>
<th>Column J</th>
<th>Column K</th>
<th>Column L</th>
<th>Column M</th>
<th>Column N</th>
<th>Column O</th>
<th>Column P</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Column text here Column text here </td>
<td>Column text here Column text here</td>
<td>Column text here Column text here</td>
<td>Column text here Column text here</td>
<td>Column text here Column text here</td>
<td>Column text here Column text here</td>
<td>Column text here Column text here</td>
<td>Column text here Column text here</td>
<td>Column text here Column text here</td>
<td>Column text here Column text here</td>
<td>Column text here Column text here</td>
<td>Column text here Column text here</td>
<td>Column text here Column text here</td>
<td>Column text here Column text here</td>
<td>Column text here Column text here</td>
<td>Column text here Column text here</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: HTML View]

[image: Print View]

Comment: *"Ideally I would just want the table to take up as much width as it needs, and if there is too much content then just wrap it normally so the letters in the words stay together."* Isn't that what already happens, by default? Can you make a screenshot?

Comment: Added screenshots.  The top is the HTML view, the bottom is print friendly view from Chrome.

Comment: I guess you would have to use a mix of `&nbsp;`, `white-space:nowrap;` in your CSS and `table {max-width:800px;}` on your `@media print` CSS. Web pages are not made to be printed but if you have to, then you need to tweak it so it looks (kind of) OK.

Comment: Where would I use &nbsp?  And where would I put the white-space property, on the td, table?

Answer (score 9):

You can use the power of viewport. Check [Here](http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/) for info

Your table style needs to be like this for @media print

```
table{
    font-size:1vw;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6aTjf/5/)** - **[DEMO PAGE FOR FIDDLE](http://fiddle.jshell.net/6aTjf/5/show/)**

Comment: IE10 still cuts off the right side (even worse than without viewport), and in Chrome the table is extremely small, both in print preview mode.

Comment: For me where the table is just cut off, the text is way too tiny

Answer (score 0):

You can give custom with to table by changing table layout to fixed.

```
table{
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```